# No numeric types to aggregate for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like this

`df`

```
id      channel           name      text
162928  p_total_2018     shintaro  myidid                
162929  Q_journey_2018   cna       mynamename
162930  p_fsdfad_2018    cna       mycomment   
.
.
```

Now I want to know how many variation of names are exist
(in this case, there are two names shintaro, cna)

but

`df.groupby('name').mean()` shows the error `No numeric types to aggregate`

How can I get the rows of no dupulicate `names`??

Comment: Check second answer in dupe.

Comment: Thank you  from dupe's second answer `.size()` works for me.